# How do i add a key value pair to an asociative array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
let finaloutput = {};
   $.each( arr, function(index,key) { 
     let outarray = [];
     // var id sourced from another function
     outarray.push(id,index,key);  
     //??finaloutput[id].push(outarray);
                        }
```

In the above code i am trying to store an object similar to below. 
Each time the loop grabs the same id it appends the array  in the finaloutput object
eg
id:index:key

1st loop where id = 7 index=param 1 key=val1

```
                  {"7":[{param1:val1}]}
```

2nd ..         id = 7 index=param 2 key=val2

```
                  {"7":[{param1:val1,param2:val2}]}
```

3rd ...        id = 8 index=param 1 key=val1

```
                  {"7":[{param1:val1,param2:val2}],"8":[{param1:val1}]}
```

How do i achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to generated similar output using sample data:

```
    `let indx = ["param1", "param2", "param3", "param4", "param5"]
    let key = ["k1", "k2", "k3", "k4", "k5"]
    let id = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
    let resultObj = {}
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      if (resultObj[id]) {
        let temp=Object.assign({}, {[indx[i]]:key[i]}, ...resultObj[id[i]])
        resultObj[id[i]] = [temp];
      }
      else{
        let ob=[{[indx[i]]:key[i]}]
        resultObj[id[i]]=ob
      }
    }
    console.log(resultObj)`
```

**In your case you can do something like :**
          `let finaloutput = {};
          $.each(arr, function (index, key) {
            if (finaloutput[id]) {
              let temp = Object.assign({}, { [index]: key }, ...finaloutput[id])
              finaloutput[id] = [temp];
            }
            else {
              let temp2 = [{ [index]: key }]
              finaloutput[id] = temp2
            }
          }`

**Note** Please refer to my example to get better understanding incase I was not able to exactly formulate answer of your code or it gives error

Comment: Welcome buddy!
I recently started with stackoverflow and this is my first accepted answer. Looking forward to contribute more 

Please do mark the answer helpful (upvote) as well if it solved your problem.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have an object `finaloutput`. So your goal can be divided into smaller pieces:

- just create a key in object
- assign an array to the above key
- push desired values into array

So the code should look like this:

```
let finaloutput = {};
$.each( arr, function(index,key) { 
    finaloutput[key] = []; 
    let outarray = [];
    // var id sourced from another function
    finaloutput[key].push({id:key});  
}
```

Or it can be done using `reduce()` method. Let me show an example::

```js
const array = ["one", "two", "three", "one", "one", "two", "two", "three", "four", "five"];

const result = array.reduce((a, c) => {
  a[c]=a[c] || [];
  a[c].push({yourKey: c});
  return a;
}, {})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Just had to change it up a bit to work , thanks .   recreating the key inside the loop causes it to reset to the last value . just had to check if the object with key existed before creating it